# What do all these backslashes mean in the library search paths in xcode "\\\\\\\"$(SRCROOT)/myprojectname\\\\\\\"?

Tags: ios, xcode, project-settings

In the Library Search Paths I have an entry that says the following:

```
\\\\\\\"$(SRCROOT)/myprojectname\\\\\\\"
```

What do all those slashes mean?

Thanks

Comment: I think it's a bug in Xcode. There is no need for the backslashes or the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean that Xcode is overzealous about escaping library search paths whenever it automatically modifies the setting. It's a bug. Delete them.